# How to add, edit and delete a vector point in Geoserver using OpenLayer 3?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-3

I'd like to add a vector point in GeoServer and then, can delete and edit it

Do you handle an example where I can study about it?

Thank you!

Comment: I read somewhere that openlayer3 has some issues with wfs-t post requests. I don't know if it true since I've never used them. But what I usually do, cause in most of my projects the editing and saving layer is not always the same, is that I am writing custom wfs-t requests and openlayer controls.  If you go to geoserver - >DEMOS you can see examples of such post requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the OpenGeo Suite SDK's ol3edit template, which is explained in this blog post: http://boundlessgeo.com/2014/07/build-apps-with-boundless-sdk-p2/.